# Поиск больших букв в предложении

Tags: javascript

Всем привет. Как мне в предложении "Андрусов Анатолий Никифорович пошёл выпить чай у берега Гудзона." найти все большие буквы и вывести массивом?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно с помощью регулярного выражения и функции `match`:

```js
var text = 'Андрусов Анатолий Никифорович пошёл выпить чай у берега Гудзона.';

var symbols = text.match(/[А-Я]/g);

console.log(symbols);
```

*P.S. Странное у вас предложение, однако :)*